# Azure site to site VPN with on-premise VPN

Tags: azure

i have succesfully(almost) configured Azure site to site vpn connection with palo alto firewall(succesfully created a tunel and the status in Azure is connected),but.. i cant access the private IP address of the VM.
We have a web based service running on https and the idea is to access this service only with VM's private ip - this means i have to dissasociate the public IP address and remove the network security group. Im struggling with the task to find how to make the private address of the VM accessible from the local network, when connected with the vpn. Can someone share some ideas ? What am i missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your Palo Alto settings.

Answer (score 0):

quick update of the topic.

1. I have the connection preconfigured, and changed the gateway mask to /27, so it can accept the virtual network.
2. Created gateway and associated it to the virtual network.
3. Created vpn and succesfully connected to the palo alto device.

The problem was the gateway subnet.